# Reporting Snapshot Mapping

Tags: reporting, analytic-snapshots, snapshot

Hello I am currently trying to create a snapshot that runs weekly on a tabular report. I am currently getting an error when the schedule job runs.

Error: "The following fields on the target object could not be mapped: Project Name,Amount Invoiced,Project Budget"

[image]

Comment: Double check the data type for source and target fields